# Can you use a ubuntu 12.10 desktop install disk like an o.e.m. disk?

Tags: installation

I recently installed a brand new hard drive and I was wondering if I need to have windows installed before Ubuntu or if it will install straight on for a clean install? My main problem is no install disk for windows... or one that would work.